# Using Global Variables with Coroutines in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code in which I launch a coroutine to handle the retrieving of data and storing them into the local database:

```
private var lastRequestedPage = 1
private var isRequestInProgress = false
private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main)

// function that is called from several places
private fun requestAndSaveData(){
    if(isRequestInProgress) return

    isRequestInProgress = true
    viewModelScope.launch{
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            // 2 heavyweight operations here:
            // retrieve some data via Retrofit & place it into the local data via Room Persistence Library
        }
    }

    lastRequestedPage++
    isRequestInProgress = false
}
```

## Description of the code snippet

The network call and database operation is done based on a boolean value called `isRequestInProgress`. When that is false, it is set to true, the network & database operations can be started by the coroutine and after that the `lastRequestedPage` is incremented before we set `isRequestInProgress` again to false so that the whole process can be started again by the program from any place. 
Note that `lastRequestedPage` is passed to the Retrofit network call function as argument since the web service from which the data comes uses Pagination (for the sake of brevity I left that out).

## My question

Can I assume that this logic works with a coroutine like this ? Can I have some bad threading issues with a solution like this ? I am asking because I am new to the concept of coroutines and I was adapting this logic from another project of mine where I used listeners&callbacks with Retrofit to perform asynchronous work(whenever the `Retrofit#onResponse` method was called I incremented `lastRequestedPage` variable and set the `isRequestInProgress` to back to false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, this won't work. It's incorrect.

When you call `viewModelScope.launch { }` or for that matter `GlobalScope.launch { }`, the block inside the `launch` gets suspended. And the program flow moves on to the next statement.

In your case, `viewModelScope.launch { }` will suspend the call to `withContext(...)` and move on to  `lastRequestedPage++` statement.

It will immediately increment the `lastRequestedPage` and toggle `isRequestInProgress` flag before even actually starting the request.

What you want to do is move those statements inside the `launch { }` block.

This is how the flow works.

- Main thread
- Suspend the block (launch call)
- Proceed forward - Don't care about the suspended block - Make UI changes, etc.

To get a better sense of how it works, try this code.

```
    Log.d("cor", "Hello, world!") // Main thread
    GlobalScope.launch {
        // Suspend this block. Wait for Main thread to be available
        Log.d("cor", "I am inside the launch block") // Main thread
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(100L) // IO thread
            Log.d("cor", "I am inside the io block") // IO thread
        }
        Log.d("cor", "IO work is done") // Back to main thread
    }
    Log.d("cor", "I am outside the launch block") // Main thread
```

The output is

```
D/cor: Hello, world!
D/cor: I am outside the launch block
D/cor: I am inside the launch block
D/cor: I am inside the io block
D/cor: IO work is done
```